# Slight anomaly with pushState - changing URL "state" on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have written the following script with a function that handles the pushState call and some jQuery which calls that function onClick:

```
function pushUrlState(id, url) {
    if (typeof (history.pushState) != "undefined") {
        var obj = { Id: id, Url: url };
        history.pushState(obj, obj.Id, obj.Url);
    } else {
        alert("This browser does not support HTML5.");
    }
}
$(function () {
    $("#id1").click(function () {
        pushUrlState('Id1', '2017/15/05/my-birthday-is-today');
    });
    $("#id2").click(function () {
        pushUrlState('Id2', '2017/14/05/my-birthday-is-tomorrow');
    });
    $("#id3").click(function () {
        pushUrlState('Id3', '2017/16/05/my-birthday-was-yesterday');
    });
});
```

Works very nicely, but after many clicks of various elements I end up with the following:

http://127.0.0.1:3000/2017/15/05/2017/14/05/2017/16/05/2017/14/05/2017/14/05/2017/14/05/2017/14/05/2017/14/05/2017/14/05/2017/14/05/2017/14/05/2017/14/05/2017/14/05/2017/14/05/2017/14/05/my-birthday-is-tomorrow

Is there some function that I can call that kills the URL back to the domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pass in a relative url (your url does not start with a `/`).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_pushState()_method

> URL — The new history entry's URL is given by this parameter. Note
>   that the browser won't attempt to load this URL after a call to
>   pushState(), but it might attempt to load the URL later, for instance
>   after the user restarts the browser. **The new URL does not need to be
>   absolute; if it's relative, it's resolved relative to the current URL.**
>   The new URL must be of the same origin as the current URL; otherwise,
>   pushState() will throw an exception. This parameter is optional; if it
>   isn't specified, it's set to the document's current URL.

Try the following 2 code snippets in the console and see the differences:

This behaves like your code (relative url)

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
.forEach(
  num =>
    //relative url (does not start with /
    history.pushState({}, `page ${num}`, `hello${num}/world${num}.html`)
)
```

This behaves like you'd like it to behave:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
.forEach(
  num =>
    //absolute url start with /
    history.pushState({}, `page ${num}`, `/hello${num}/world${num}.html`)
)
```

Comment: Worked liked a charm - apologies for not accepting this question sooner.